# Drupal 7: user is following view

Tags: 7, views, users

I need to create a view of people a user is following. the default settings for user relationships only shows people following a user. i know i need to use views but i have no clue how to set it up. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just had a problem that took me forever on a View to do with User Relationships, on [question #25294](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/25294/3966).

The [screenshot of the View](http://www.flickr.com/photos/owenblacker/6978926279) I was debugging and the information I put in my question should hopefully give you everything you need.

(Bear in mind that my View was getting the people following $currentuser, whereas you want the people $currentuser is following, so you'll want to reverse all the instances of `requester` and `requestee`.)

I hope this helps!

Comment: No problem; I'm glad it helped  :)